# Setup domino server to send email to internet for local users with @localdomain.com (-> email move to google)

Tags: email, ibm, ibm-domino

My domino server hold an application who generate email for users.
Mails file moved to Google.
But email still redirect to local mail file and not google mailfile.
What to change to send email from the domino server to internet for local user?

Answer (score 0):

Just tell your Domino, that it is not responsible for localdomain.com anymore.

Change your "Global Domain" document and remove that Domain. Then restart the router: From that moment the Domino server will not think anymore that it is responsible for that domain and will route the mails same as every other external mail.

Answer (score 0):

I use the advice, but had to complete it.
When deleting the "Domain document", emails from the local domain do not route to Internet and stayed in the Mailbox (pending mail).
So I had a smarthost, in the Messaging setting document.
Documentation.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_settingupasmarthost_t.html

Thank you very much for the help.